# Rails and AngularJS ngResource: Creating a custom REST operation to access models attached to a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I am creating a web application that utilizes Rails 3 to serve up JSON. I use AngularJS' `ngResource` to interact with the RESTful server-side data.

On the rails side, I have two models: Genre and Book.

- Each Genre `has_many` Books
- Each Book `belongs_to` a Genre
- In `routes.rb`, my resources are listed as `resources :genres, :books`. They are not nested.

As I'm sure you know, this allows me to do things like call `Genre.where(name: "sci-fi").first.books` that returns me an array.

I'd like to do something like this from the Rails controller and the Angular `ngResource` factory. It's working properly for me for the standard `REST` operations...

However, I'm trying to define a custom `REST` operation where I could call something like this: `Genre.books({ id: 1 })` and have it return an array of books that belongs to the Genre with an id of 1.

Here's my `genres_controller.rb`:

```
class GenresController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  ... 

  def books
    @genre_books = Genre.where(id: params[:id]).first.books
    respond_with @genre_books
  end
end
```

Here's my Angular `ngResource` for genre (written in coffeescript):

```
app = angular.module("ATWP")

app.factory "Genre", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/genres/:id",
    id: "@id"
  ,
    ....

    books:
      method: "GET"
```

I've tried tacking on `isArray: true` to the `REST` operation to no avail. I simply get back the Genre resource itself but not an array of books that belong to the Genre.

So, what am I missing? Is it a bad idea in the first place to do something like what I'm trying to do in the above examples? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created new controller action 'books', route resources will not pick it up. You should define custom route like `match '/genrebooks/:id', to: 'genres#books', via: :get` . Aafter that you should update your factory to match the new route.

Comment: I rewrote my Angular resource, which can be found here in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h1Yx9av6esJof8JBjJLh?p=catalogue).  

Is this the correct way to update the resource? I just tried doing it this way and I get a TypeError whenever I try to access Genre.index().

Comment: My bad, I should of told you to create new factory for the new route as well. 
app.factory "GenreBooks"
  $resource "/genrebooks/:id",
    id: "@id"
  ,
    books:
      method: "GET"
      isArray: true
When that is done call the new factory from the controller.

Comment: So it works. Thank you for your help! 

Thinking about it though, would it make more sense to nest the Book resource under Genre in the Rails routes file? The only problem I have is that there are times I'd like to get all Books, regardless of Genres.

Comment: It all depends on the app your building, personally in your case I'll keep it separate since you need Books without Genre. It will be easier to maintain and read later on.